# Make telephone call on a button click in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have implemented a telephonic service in my app their is a button when we click on that button it will make a call but the problem is it not supporting all devices on some devices it is working well and in some devices it is not working now provide me any solution what to do so that it work on all devices.
here is my code.

> ```
> public class SOSCallHelp extends AppCompatActivity {
> private Button call1;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_soscall_help);
>     call1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.call1);
>
>   call1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
>             callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9078784565"));
>             if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SOSCallHelp.this,
>                     Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
>
>             {
>                 return;
>             }
>             startActivity(callIntent);
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: `some devices it is not working ` what problem ?? crashing

Comment: Let me guess, it's not working on new Android versions?

Comment: Have you given Android 6.0 permissions

Comment: no i had not given 6.0 permission and where to give that @Ramesh

Comment: App is not crashing in some devices it make a call on button click and in some devices nothing happened on button click.That is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add the below permission in your App Manifest for Pre-Lollipop devices.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Request Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

For Calling

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9078784565"));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SOSCallHelp.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

        {
            return;
        }
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       try this:

    final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;

       if (driverMobile != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                // Marshmallow+
                if (!checkCallPhonePermission() || !checkReadStatePermission()) {
                    requestPermission();
                } else {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 1234567899));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            } else {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + + 1234567899));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        } else {

        }
```

//permission

```
  private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 
PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}


 private void requestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
 {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 
 PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODES);
} 


 private boolean checkCallPhonePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean checkReadStatePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}



  @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String 
 permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 123456789
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
            break;
  }

  }
```

Comment: i had tried all the above code but no one is working uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_CALL" Action call is not available in manifest default permissions/

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />  put this permission in manifest and use above code

Comment: I have already put this permission  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> 
but still it is not recognizing symbol ACTION_CALL

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+123456789"));
                    startActivity(intent);   use this

Answer (score 0):

Please change to this -

```
public class SOSCallHelp extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button call1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_soscall_help);
        call1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call1);

        call1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9078784565"));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SOSCallHelp.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

                {
                    return;
                }
                PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                if (callIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } else {
                    Log.d("SOSCallHelp", "No Intent available to handle this action");
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
 private static int REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 111;

 private void requestCallPhonePermission() {
    String callPermission = android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
    int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SOSCallHelp.this, callPermission);
    String[] permissions = new String[]{callPermission};
    if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9078784565"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CALL_PHONE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9078784565"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SOSCallHelp.this, "CALL_PHONE DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}
```

Now call this `requestCallPhonePermission()` function on button click

In manifest file add     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`
 permission.

Comment: HEY this code open atleat dial screen and also dial the number but to dont make call its gives security Exception

Comment: Not exactly. what happen here that on some devices it make a call success on other devices but on some devices it just dial the number but could not connect to that particular no that is on dialer screen.If you have any idea to solve this version support issue then please let me know. Thankyou.

Comment: @AnkitaSethi Tell me the android os version in which it is not working. It will be worked in all devices. This is my working code

Comment: Android version 6.0, Model name Lenovo K50a40 also some other higher versions but working in 4.2.2 properly

Comment: @AnkitaSethi Did u use my code ?? Can you mail me your code ?

Comment: Can you mail me your code for particular that activity class? @AnkitaSethi

Comment: @AnkitaSethi got it or not?

Comment: Yes check your Email Please.